# Issues using python for CGI

Tags: python, apache, cgi, syntax-error

For some reason, I have to use semicolons in my python cgi script. Also, it doesn't recognize the usual syntax for if statements.

For example, this works:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>Hello World!</html>";
```

but this does not work:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html>Hello World!</html>"
```

and this does not work:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
if True:
    print "<html>Hello World!</html>";
```

I get 500 Internal Server Errors from the last two examples. My apache error log says that there are syntax issues in the file. I am on OSX running this on Apache2. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: So obviously this is not being handled as a python script. I think I may have found the problem, but I"m not sure how to fix it. In my httpd.conf I have the following lines appended to the end and I think they are the issue:

```
<Location /cgi-bin>
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
    Options ExecCGI
    PerlSendHeader On
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

I have these lines in order for some other cgi scripts in my cgi-bin to be run with mod_perl. If this needs to be changed, what should it look like so that the perl cgi files will still be run under mod_perl, but the python cgi files will be run as python? For clarity or in case it matters, the perl files in my cgi-bin have a .cgi file extension, but the python cgi file that I am trying to get working has a .py file extension.

Comment: Try removing the space after `#!`. It sounds like your script is being run by something other than the Python interpreter.

Comment: tried it, didn't work. in terminal, "whereis python" returns /usr/bin/python so i think i'm in the right place

Comment: So, what are the error messages you get in the error log file?

Comment: Are you sure that python is actually located at `/usr/bin/python`? What does `which python` say?

Comment: [error] syntax error at /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/blah.py line 5, near "if True"\n

Comment: which python also returns /usr/bin/python

Comment: >>> print dir()
    ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']

Comment: if i remove the first #! line, it does not change any of my problems. The same examples above have the same behavior

Comment: It looks like Apache is assuming your script is Perl rather than Python. Does your server have mod_perl installed or vanilla CGI? What does your httpd.conf have in the way of CGI configuration?

Comment: If you have mod_perl installed rather than CGI, I don't think you are going to be able to convince it to run Python. You should install the equivalent mod_python.

Comment: so you're saying I cannot have mod_perl running and also be able to execute python scripts at the same time?

Comment: Python CGI is slow, the state-of-the art is `mod_wsgi` (for Apache). If you are new to Python web programming, you should take a look at frameworks like Django or micro-frameworks like bottle.py or flask.

Comment: mod_perl is only for running Perl scripts for CGI. If you want to run Python script as CGI you are going to have to install mod_python, mod_wsgi, vanilla CGI, or some other Apache mod that can run Python scripts. Your httpd.conf is telling Apache: treat ALL files in this directory at CGI scripts that should be handled by mod_perl. If you install mod_wsgi or one of the others you should be able to run both Perl or Python scripts, but you are going to have modify your httpd.conf so that Apache can figure out which is the appropriate mod to  use.

Comment: To (hopefully) clarify what Charles said, you don't need to install *anything* to run Python scripts as traditional CGI scripts, but you will probably need to put them somewhere other than where've you've told Apache to use `mod_perl`.  Your scripts will be more performant if you run them using `mod_python` or `mod_wsgi`.

Answer (score 0):

Your apache configuration is explictly set to run things in the cgi-bin directory as `Perl` - 
and this is because your Syntax is "strange" - it only works when it is a perl program.

Stand alone print statements ending with `;`appen to be valid both Python 2.x and perl.

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html, this is all you need to 
get your CGI's properlyworking, without enforcing perl to handle them:

```
<Directory /cgi-bin>
Options ExecCGI
SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
```